# Match words in the middle

Tags: python, regex

Suppose that I want to match the first two texts but not the third.

```py
import pandas as pd

test_text = [
"Command to remove :: blah Reason for removal:",
"Command to be removed :: Command (<NAME>) Reason for removal:",
"Command to <RANDOM-WORD> removed :: Command (<NAME>) Reason for removal:"
]

df = pd.DataFrame({"text": test_text})
df["text"].str.contains(my_regex) # REQUIRED OUTPUT: True, True, False
```

The only thing I can think of is `my_regex = r"Command to (be)? remove"`. However, this is not matching with sentences containing `"be"`. What's the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Because you have an extra space. Include a space before or after ‘be’ in the parentheses and delete one from outside

Comment: Try: `my_regex = r"Command to (?:be )?removed?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make white-space before or after "be" optional. If you have variation of  "removed" and "remove" in sentences make "d" in removed optional as well.

```
r"Command to\s?(be)? removed?"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
my_regex = r"Command to (([b][e] )|)remove"
```